# How to import and edit an excel template for a phonegap application?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, cordova

I need to import an excel template and edit it (add data) as part of a phonegap application: The idea is to load an excel file and turn it to a html table where the user may add data, still I can't figure out how to code it using javascript.

Can you help me, or give me hints, on how i could achive this maybe?

Comment: You're not going to be able to do it with JavaScript alone. You will, at the very least, need some sort of server side language to upload the document before you can crack it open and view its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

1. Use this plugin [Phonegap plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader) and read excel as text file (.txt).
2. Text file's content will be filled with rows and columns. each rows will be separated with some unique character in that text file and then split it with that unique character
3. Construct html table with retrieved data.
4. To save the same follow the same link which is having `FileTransfer()` function to save file as excel.

Comment: That's what I intented to do still my pbm is about getting unreadable text when I use readAsText for the excel file

Comment: There are certain reasons that phonegap doesn't have plugins for reading excel sheets. But we can do it in some different way. For that you have to work little bit on native side. You need to read excel sheet from native code and save it in common DB or text file. Then let JavaScript access  that. This is the only way if you can not read excel as a text through that plugin.